# CreateContext not updating children when performin Authenticaion

Tags: reactjs

I have a login component from which i try to save the authenticated user's data into the AuthContext using a custom `useAuth()` hooks. But when i set the value from within login component AuthContext never get updated and the auth object is null, but when i set the AuthContext from within another componenet it got updated as expected and i could access it from other component. what might be the reason behind this weird behaviour

import useAuth from "../../hooks/useAuth";

```
const {auth,  setAuth} = useAuth();

 useEffect(() => {
    console.log(auth)
  }, [auth]);

const submitHandler = async (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  try {
    const response = await axios.post(LOGIN_URL,
        JSON.stringify({ username, password }),
        {
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
            withCredentials: true
        }
    );
    
    const accessToken = response.data ? response.data.accessToken : null;
    const user = response.data ? response.data.user : null;
    // setAuth({
    //   accessToken:accessToken,
    //   user:user
    // });
    const obj =   {
        "accessToken": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIser5taSI6Im1AMkh0a3k2KnQ5aWZlIn0.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwczpcL1wvYXBpLmNoZWNrc3RhbGwuY29tIiwiYXVkIjoiaHR0cHM6cdfrt2FwaS5jaGVja3N0YWxsLmNvbSIsImp0aSI6Im1AMkh0a3k2KnQ5aWZlIiwiaWF0IjoxNjY3NTkwMjg3LCJleHAiOjE2Njc1OTA1ODcsInVpZCI6MX0.4LYi3eDW6mfKB9H_vOjhfqttKoT1dGUdJuisU3esdwt",
        "user": {
            "username": "bob01",
            "email": "bob@yahoo.com",
            "created_at": 1659239223,
            "full_name": "Bob L",
            "role": 40,
            "phone_number": "199765432",
            "last_login": 16647884254
        }
    }
    setAuth(obj);
    setUsername('');
    setPassword('');

    //navigate(-1);
    setModalShow(false);
}catch(err){
    if (err.response) {
     //do something
        
    } else{
        //do something
      }
  }

}
```

after async call the useEffect got called and log the result as expected but when i set the same result into the AuthContext through the useAuth hooks it never go updated

Below is my useAuth hooks

```
import { useContext, useDebugValue } from "react";
import AuthContext from "../context/AuthProvider";

const useAuth = () => {
    const { auth } = useContext(AuthContext);
    if (auth === undefined) {
    throw new Error("useUserContext can only be used inside AuthProvider");
    }
    return useContext(AuthContext);
}

export default useAuth;
```

and also my AuthContext Provider

```
import React ,{ createContext, useState, useMemo } from "react";

const AuthContext = createContext({});

export const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [auth, setAuth] = useState({});
    const [persist, setPersist] = useState(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("persist")) || false);
    const value = useMemo(() => ({ 
        auth, setAuth ,persist ,setPersist
    }), [auth, setAuth, persist,setPersist]);

    return (
        <AuthContext.Provider value={value}>{children}</AuthContext.Provider>
    )
}

export default AuthContext;
```